# MSAL - Redirect URI and token

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using Microsoft's MSAL library in my Angular SPA application. There is a way to configure the `reidrectUri` setting.  From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reply-url), I see that the significance of this Uri is:

> A redirect URI, or reply URL, is the location where the authorization server sends the user once the app has been successfully authorized and granted an authorization code or access token.

In my case, I extract token information by using MSAL LOGIN_SUCCESS event.

```
  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    filter(
      (msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS
    ),
    takeUntil(this._destroying$)
  )
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    const payload = result.payload as AuthenticationResult;  // get account information here. 
    this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
  });
}
```

Am I supposed to read the token from the redirect URI? My guess is that getting the token manually at the redirect URI endpoint is not required. I can use MSAL (as shown above) to get the token information. Is this correct or am I missing something?